# Android root access script

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, apk

I need help with this script, can someone tell me what did I do wrong?
I'm trying to make a root checker on startup.

1. Check write access
2. ReturnaAlert of no root
3. Exit on press exit (TO DO)

Here's the exact Java snippet I'm building

```
{
        Process p;
    try
    { 
        //  Run root command
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 

        // Attempt to write a file to system
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream()); 
        os.writeBytes("echo \"Do I have root?\" >/system/temporary.txt\n");

        // Close the stream
        os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
        os.flush(); 
        try
        { 
            p.waitFor(); 
            if (p.exitValue() != 255)
            { 
                // Code to run on ROOTED
                //  NOTHING JUST GO FORWARD
            }
            else
            { 
                // Code to run on NON ROOTED

            } 
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        { {
            // TODO Code to run with interrupted exception

            }
        } 
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    { 
        // TODO Code to run in input/output exception

    }}}
```

The APK file is built [here](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=kZ3XDSZla782IpIsWYTLD6Kf5r3bzBDxnvy) for testers.

The root snippets source comment [here](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=33450)

Comment: While the issue may have been fixed, never "erase" your question. If you wish it to be erased, delete it. If not, leave it as is, since other users may have similar problems, and can read it, and try to understand your problem, and if the solutions presented could help them.

Comment: @Bonatti Thanks Bonatti, i will fix the original question for others... I found that i had written the id wrong so i fixed the issue with an extra `ELSE IF`

Comment: please do not vandalize your own questions/answers by deleting all the content in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually to check for root, you have to check your "userid", from the Linux command `id`.

So instead of:

`os.writeBytes("echo \"Do I have root?\" >/system/temporary.txt\n");`

use:

`os.writeBytes("id\n"); os.flush();`

Then read the response, with something such as:

`DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(p.getInputStream());`

And check the result with:

`if (data .readLine().contains("uid=0"));`

Edit:

I use the following Root Privileges class on my apps:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Root related operations.
 */
public class RootPrivileges {
    public static final String TAG = "RootPrivileges";

    private RootPrivileges() {
        Log.e(TAG, "RootPrivileges should not be instantiated");
    }

    /**
     * Checks and asks for Root privileges
     *
     * @return true if has root privileges, false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean hasRoot() {
        boolean resp = false;
        Process suProcess;
        try {
            suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream osRes = new DataInputStream(suProcess.getInputStream());
            if (os != null && osRes != null) {
                os.writeBytes("id\n");
                os.flush();
                String currUid = osRes.readLine();
                boolean exitSu;
                if (null == currUid) {
                    resp = false;
                    exitSu = false;
                    Log.e(TAG, "No root privileges, or denied by user");
                } else if (currUid.contains("uid=0")) {
                    resp = true;
                    exitSu = true;
                    Log.v(TAG, "Root privileges given");
                } else {
                    resp = false;
                    exitSu = true;
                    Log.e(TAG, "Not enough privileges.\n   Received: " + currUid + "\n   Expected: 0");
                }
                if (exitSu) {
                    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                    os.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            resp = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "Root privileges denied. [" + e.getClass().getName() + "] : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return resp;
    }

    /**
     * Executes a command as root.
     *
     * @param cmd the command.
     * @return if code was sent to execute
     */
    public static final boolean execute(String cmd) {
        try {
            if (cmd != null && cmd.length() > 0) {
                Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
                DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(suProcess.getInputStream());
                DataInputStream dataErrorStream = new DataInputStream(suProcess.getErrorStream());

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(cmd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("\n");
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream));
                BufferedReader err_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataErrorStream));
                String resp;
                while ((resp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "[resp]" + resp);
                }
                while ((resp = err_reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "[err_resp]" + resp);
                }
                reader.close();
                err_reader.close();
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                try {
                    int suProcessRetval = suProcess.waitFor();
                    suProcess.destroy();
                    return (suProcessRetval != 255);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error in Root command execution");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "command is null or empty");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Generic Exception");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the code i provided and re answer ! - I'm a newbie ! ..   Also can you have a look at the exit code, i cant find any working method to close the app completely

Comment: As far as Android goes, you should never "close the application", it takes more eletricity to prepare everything and allocate than it does in the Android memory management system. You should read about the ["Android Lifecycle"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to better understand how the apps should behave. If this is in the context of an Activity, just `finish()` that activity. As far as Super User / Switch User, this class has always worked well for me.

Comment: Normally this would be true, but the app is only designed for pressing install or remove buttons, The remove button also closes and uninstalls the app it's self, by running a .sh script file.... So constantly running it is not possible.

Comment: Well, you could always "close" yourself with `System.exit(0)` then.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go ... I've tried with a few, but the problem seems to be around the ELSE command, Once i press deny root, it still loads as if I've got root

Comment: Are you using this class? If so, `RootPrivileges.hasRoot()` should always block the app, wait for some "root granting" app to appear, should you press no in it, then hasRoot() returns false.

Comment: https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=kZ3XDSZla782IpIsWYTLD6Kf5r3bzBDxnvy   ...   ... .... The file called BROKEN START IS THE CURRENT DEBUG BUILD, SO YOU CAN SEE THE START UP ISSUE...

Comment: Can you simplify your answer.. I used the `id=0` method, but it causes a white screen and freezes after accepting root

Comment: Hmm. This behavior is unexpected. What Android version are you running this on, also, do you know what rooting process was used, and is the `su` binary present and working correctly on other `su` commands? The white screen is most likely that you are asking for root before setting a Layout in the activity. I have seen "lags" but not ANRs (Application Not Responding") in some Samsung devices, I have also seen a "lag" when the device is rooted with "Kingroot" or some of its competitors. ChainFire's "SuperSu" was the best I have worked with so far. If necessary, ask for root on an AsynkTask.